# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on Pro ASP.Net Book MVC3 Framework and suddenly I have this issue.

I am attaching the code for my Product Controller. Seems like problem is here:

Also, I added code for my NinjectController. Would appreciate any help with code.

```
namespace NordStore.WebUI.Controllers{
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }

}
```

}

```
namespace NordStore.WebUI.Infrastructure{
 public class NinjectControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext,
            Type controllerType)
        {

            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            // put additional bindings here

            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Continue reading the chapter. I guess it'll handle dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor takes a parameter of type IProductRepository. You are probably trying to instantiate your controller like so:

```
    ProductController controller = new ProductController();
```

But you can't because there is no Constructor that is defined in your controller that takes 0 arguments. You need to either pass an object of type IProductRepository or define a paramterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at Dependency Injection frameworks like Unity or Ninject.

In the meanwhile to get your code to work your the poor man's DI method:
Assuming `ProductRepository` derives from `IProductRepository`

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    //The framework will call this constructor
    public ProductController() : this(new ProductRepository()) { }

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }

}
```

Comment: Dear @Abhi, please take a look at my question again. I am using Ninject. If you could help me, it would be great. My project due is tomorrow.

Comment: Install Ninject.MVC3 from Nuget, if you are using ASP MVC4. You wont need your `NinjectControllerFactory` then. After installing go to App_start and register your mappings in the `RegisterServices()` method of `NinjectWebCommon.cs`, like so:
`kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();`